# how to get script name and id from scriplet in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, scriptlet

How could we get all script name and script id in array I want it to be shown in dropdown in my application.
Here is my code which is only giving me filename I am not getting external url like this

https://4512314-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=692&deploy=1

here is my code

```
function searchScriptFile()
{

  var folderid = 'SuiteScripts';

    var filters = new Array();
    filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('name', null, 'is', folderid);

    var columns = new Array();
    var filename = new nlobjSearchColumn('name', 'file');
    var fileid = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', 'file');
    var path = new nlobjSearchColumn('url', 'file');

    columns[0] = filename;
    columns[1] = fileid;
    columns[2] = path;

    var searchResult = nlapiSearchRecord('folder', null , filters , columns);

    var res = new Array();
    if(searchResult) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
        thisfile = searchResult[i].getValue(filename);
        thisfileid = searchResult[i].getValue(fileid);
        thispath = searchResult[i].getValue(path);
          res[i] =  thisfile + ' ' + thisfileid + ' ' + thispath;
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Test', thisfileid + ' ' + thisfile);
        }
      return res[27];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need NetSuite File Cabinet script details or SuiteScript details?

Comment: I want suitescript details

Comment: Then you need to create search on scriptdeployment and not on folder

Comment: @Avi I tried to search script deployment but not able to find any way to search this can you please help me with some code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for the script deployments, not the files in the file cabinet.

```
var scriptdeploymentSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("scriptdeployment",null,
[
], 
[
   new nlobjSearchColumn("title").setSort(false), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("scriptid"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("script"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("scriptid","script",null), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("recordtype"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("status"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("isdeployed"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("scripttype"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("ismobilemenu"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("apiversion","script",null)
]
);
```

Comment: how could I get all script name as I want to show that in dropdown?

Comment: I tried with this code but when I try to call getValue() method its showing undefined method I am not able to get any columns details

Comment: add this column new nlobjSearchColumn("name","script",null) and then when looping the results you would do something like this: for(var i=0; i<scriptdeploymentSearch.length; i++){
var result = scriptdeploymentSearch[i];
var scriptName = result.getValue('name','script');
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to run search on **scriptdeployment**(as suggested above by *dcrs*) and not on **folder**. Although I didn't find any way to fetch *externalurl* of the script-deployement, guess NetSuite doesn't support it yet.
Here is the basic code to on ScriptDeploymemts though

```
search.create({ 
  type: 'scriptdeployment', 
  columns: ['script.scriptfile', 'title',
    'scriptid', 'script.apiversion']
}).run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });
```